# Recover files from formatted partition

Tags: linux, hard-drive, partitioning, data-recovery

My external HDD suddenly decided that it doesn't want to mount one of the partitions anymore. When trying to open under Windows, I got "corrupted partition. Can't open" type of error. So I just formatted that dude, but it would be nice to recover some files.

I tried with `R-Linux` GUI software and was unsuccessful - could not read any deleted files. Then decided to try the good old `TestDisk` in the terminal. I go to `Advanced Filesystem Utils` and then for the selected partition I choose `Undelete` but cannot find any deleted files.

I haven't installed any OS on top of that drive after it has been formatted. Not even a single `.txt` file has been copied to the drive after the formatting.

Is the recovery of any files doomed? Do you have any magical suggestions?

P.S. I formatted the partition from Windows, and the partition itself is `NTFS`.

Comment: Try `ddrescue` (not `dd_rescue`). Get some hint maybe [here](https://vtopan.wordpress.com/2009/11/15/recovering-data-from-a-dead-windows-ntfs-disk-using-linux/)... but if, when you have formatted your HDD, you have done _not in a Quick way_ you have overwritten all the empty space and it will be really difficult to find something...

Comment: It was a *quick format*. So, that's why I am hoping for smth :D

Comment: `ddrescue` is to make a raw copy, after or even directly, you can use [`PhotoRec`](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).  (_PhotoRec ignores the file system; this way it works even if the file system is severely damaged._). Let me know __if__ it works... [and it is not because is named __Photo__ rec that it can see the disk _image_ :-) ] BTW if you have _space_ and _time_ you can find a lot of forensic and administrative tools to help you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to recover data in formatted hard disk and already installed a new OS](http://superuser.com/questions/790527/how-to-recover-data-in-formatted-hard-disk-and-already-installed-a-new-os)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you are not doomed, **not yet!**
Not until you will try all the method known to restore your data!

Since you said you have done a *"Quick format"*, the procedure

> leaves all your data in place and makes the drive appear to be empty. [1]

Probably you can try easily [Photorec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) since you have just installed `testdisk`.

If the *HDD* had physical damages and you have enough space elsewhere you can do a raw copy with `ddrescue` (not `dd_rescue`) and then work on that one in order to minimize the possibility to [*brick*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brick_%28electronics%29) your *HDD*.

**References:**

1. [How to format a hard drive in Windows...](http://www.pcadvisor.co.uk/how-to/storage/how-format-hard-drive-in-windows-3470977/)
2. On [*"Forensics Wiki"*](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/Ddrescue)
3. On [*"What's the difference between ddrescue, gddrescue, and dd_rescue?"*](https://askubuntu.com/a/211579/196535)
4. On internet [*"LINUX - dd_rescue VS ddrescue (gddrescue BEST)"*](http://www.kossboss.com/linux---dd_rescue-vs-ddrescue)
5. Another [answer](https://superuser.com/a/980279/257269) applicable.