# Is it possible to recover a directory on Linux?

Tags: linux, data-recovery

I did something stupid:

```
/trunk/vmware$ du -h svn
6,1G    svn
/trunk/vmware$ sudo mkdir -p /data/vmware
/trunk/vmware$ (sudo tar cf - svn) | (sudo cd /data/vmware; sudo tar xf -)
sudo: cd: command not found
^C^C^C/trunk/vmware$ du -h /trunk/vmware/svn/
3,5G    /trunk/vmware/svn/
```

Not only was my directory not copied, but it was damaged in such a way that I lost 3 GB. The virtual machine does not start of course. Is there any chance I can recover the data. I have Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with ext4.

Comment: Give a look [here](http://superuser.com/a/980853/257269) too... photorec, ddrescue... but it is better if you can mount that partition read only.

Answer (score 2):

You aren't going to restore your files in any manner other than scouring blocks on the hard drive. Shut that computer down immediately, slave the drive to another system (or boot up off of some kind of a recovery CD), and use file recovery tools on it such as [PhotoRec](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec).

Comment: I unmounted the disk and disabled the mount in /etc/fstab but I wonder if it is worth it if the procedure is so complex. I have an old version of the SVN database backed up and probably all changed data is checked out in local folders. Maybe I will simply rebuild the virtual machine from that back-up Thanks for the advice.