# Restore deleted data from a specific partition

Tags: restore

I got my laptop formatted and accidentally (full format) so data and files of disc D got deleted and (the two discs C and D are one place) I'm trying to restore it. But it's the first time I've done this restoring thing and chose the same source as destination location!

What happens now (note: restoration process hasn't completed yet) and those files are super important to me!

Will restoration process still be effective this way!
What should I do?
I turned off my laptop (pause) while restoring so the process hasn't completed yet!

Comment: Since the data is "super important," to you,  **do not try to restore it yourself**, particularly since, "it's the first time I've done this." Turn off the PC and take it to data restoration specialists. It may be costly. However, it is likely your attempt to fix the issue has further damaged data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to recover data in formatted hard disk and already installed a new OS](https://superuser.com/questions/790527/how-to-recover-data-in-formatted-hard-disk-and-already-installed-a-new-os)